# Accessing the properties of a referenced Mongoose schema using Angular expressions

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I am developing a basic event management app using the MEAN stack.

I have the following Event schema:

```
var eventSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    host: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
    ...
}
```

which references a User schema that contains a name, username, and password.

I am trying to display the data of Event objects in my HTML view with Angular expressions using double curly braces (i.e. `{{ event.name }}`).

My question is: is it possible to access the properties of the referenced User using double curly braces? I want to be able to display the `User`'s username in my view. `{{ event.host }}` only outputs the ObjectId of the User while `{{ event.host.username }}` is undefined.

I've tried populating the `host` path before even saving the `Event`, but population seems to be confined where I called it; for example, I can populate from within api.js and access the `User` properties, but I can't access the same property outside.

How can I access the properties of a referenced schema?

---

I'm new to web development, so I'm not sure if I'm doing things the right way. If it helps, I followed *Mean Machine: The Beginner's Guide to the JavaScript Stack* by the guys from Scotch.

Comment: you need to create the api to access the data in angularjs

Comment: Thanks! I've done that, though. I can access the data, but the data only contains the ObjectId of the host. Should I manipulate the data at this point before passing it to the service?

Comment: yes its seem easy to manipulate it .just use the dot notation in view

Comment: can you please show me the object ? what you recieved on server